# Error in IBM Cloud API PCloudInstances request

Tags: api, ibm-cloud

I am trying to make this request from IBM Cloud API: [Documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/power-cloud#pcloud-cloudinstances-get)

I have successfully made other requests like pvmInstances and Volumes, so we should have the permission, but this one returns this error: {'description': 'Your access token is invalid or does not have the necessary '
'permissions to perform this task.',
'error': 'Access Denied'}.

Is there anyone who can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you can perform the actions in the IBM Cloud Console UI.  If that works OK, then login using the CLI and get the tokens as described in the docs to use curl
[image: cli login]

Comment: I have the permission apparently as I am able to make all requests listed in the documentation, but for the PCloudInstances one I get this error...